# CFReadStreamRef always nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-foundation

I'm trying to read `public.pem` file where public key is stored, but `CFReadStreamRef` always return nil. `publicKeyPath` and `url` are not nil (as I can see at debugger) and I don't have other threads reading or writing to the file. How can I fix this?

```
NSString *publicKeyPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"public" ofType:@"pem"];
CFURLRef url  = (CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain([NSURL URLWithString:publicKeyPath]);
CFReadStreamRef cfrs = CFReadStreamCreateWithFile(kCFAllocatorDefault, url);
```

Answer (score 1):

I should have used `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:publicKeyPath]`

Comment: Whilst it's fine to answer your own question, you really need to provide a bit more information than this, so that this question/answer becomes a useful resource for others.

Comment: @middaparka I'd argue that the arguments in favor of using the vastly more user-friendly NSURL classes, over the more low-level CF classes, are self-evident to the degree that they don't need explanation.  Why dip down any lower than you absolutely have to?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *publicKeyPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"public" ofType:@"pem"];
```

This will return something like `/private/var/mobile/.../public.pem`, or `/foo/bar` for short.

```
CFURLRef url  = (CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain([NSURL URLWithString:publicKeyPath]);
```

This will create a URL from the *string* `/foo/bar`. This is a perfectly valid relative URL (it links to `scheme://authority/foo/bar` where `scheme://authority` is determined by the base URL.

What you want is an *absolute file URL*, which means you want `+fileURLWithPath:`. Alternatively, use `-URLForResource:withExtension:`, which will give you a file URL from the very beginning:

```
NSURL *url= [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"public.pem" withExtension:nil];
CFReadStreamRef cfrs = CFReadStreamCreateWithFile(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFURLRef)url);
```